# How to split H256 into u32, u112, u112 in Rust

Tags: rust

`0x638d0490000000004b7cdeca2fe41a1b6411000000158fb5610df6aa553bfedb` of type `H256`

https://docs.rs/ethers/0.17.0/ethers/types/struct.H256.html#

It is a storage slot on EVM. A single slot is uint256, but there, three different values were packed into one storage slot (thats how EVM works). So uint112 + uint112 + uint32 were packed into uint256 that I need to reverse engineer.

Looking to get:

1. `0x638d049`
2. `0x4b7cdeca2fe41a1b6411`
3. `0x158fb5610df6aa553bfedb`

Then (1, 2, 3) into (u32, u128, u128) - u128 as the closet one to uint112.

Tried a few things with padding but does not seem to be optimal (looping thru).

Comment: Can you clarify for me how the split should be occurring? Are you splitting at the zeros?

Comment: Yes please :D what does this mean? Where does any of this come from? What's the content of the `h256`? What's a `h256`? Why `u32,u128,u128`? Why does your question say `u32, u112, u112`? Why does your input number look more like 28-116-112? What's the point of any of this?

Comment: sorry, my bad, added info above, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract them manually using bitshifts like this:

```rust
use num::BigUint;
fn main() {
    let a = BigUint::parse_bytes(b"638d0490000000004b7cdeca2fe41a1b6411000000158fb5610df6aa553bfedb", 16).unwrap();
    println!("{a:#x}");
    let x = a.clone() >> (2*112);
    let y = (a.clone() >> 112) & ((BigUint::from(1u8) << 112) - 1u8);
    let z = a.clone() & ((BigUint::from(1u8) << 112) - 1u8);
    println!("{x:#x}");
    println!("{y:#x}");
    println!("{z:#x}");
}
```

Comment: thats exactly what i did! )) thought something elegant but yh i guess thats the only option